# Form creates object, but params not passed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm trying to create a simple form submission to create posts for a blog-type site. I can't seem to get the form to submit the params. If I remove the validations in the model, I can create objects with unique IDs, but they're completely blank as far as the params go.

posts_controller.rb

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @posts = Post.all
end

def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @post = Post.new
end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post), :notice => "Post was created successfully."
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private
def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:id)
end
```

new.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <% if @post.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
   <ul>
     <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
     <div><%= msg %></div>
     <% end %>
    </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
 <% end %>

<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <ol class="formdivst">
  <%= f.label :title %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.label :content_md %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :content_md %>
<div>
  <%= f.file_field :image %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
</ol>
<% end %>
```

posts.rb (model)

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Use friendly_id
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :title, use: :slugged

  # Markdown
  #before_save { MarkdownWriter.update_html(self) }

  # Validations
  validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 100 }, uniqueness: true
  validates :content_md, presence: true

  # Pagination
  paginates_per 30

  # Relations
  belongs_to :user

  # Scopes
  scope :published, lambda {
    where(draft: false)
    .order("updated_at DESC")
  }

  scope :drafted, lambda {
    where(draft: true)
    .order("updated_at DESC")
  }

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { small: "64x64", med: "100x100", large: "200x200" }

end
```

routes.rb

```
app::Application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home"
  resources :posts
  get "home", to: "pages#home", as: "home"
  get "inside", to: "pages#inside", as: "inside"
  get "/contact", to: "pages#contact", as: "contact"
  post "/emailconfirmation", to: "pages#email", as: "email_confirmation"

  devise_for :users

  namespace :admin do
    resources :posts
    root "base#index"
    resources :users
    get "posts/drafts", to: "posts#drafts", as: "posts_drafts"
    get "posts/dashboard", to: "posts#dashboard", as: "posts_dashboard"
  end

end
```

Comment: Are you using Rails 4 ? If yes, then make sure you use correctly Strong Parameters in your controller to permit/require certain fields (https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) (see your `create` action: `Post.new(post_params)` here `post_params` should return a hash containing the allowed attributes)

Comment: @MrYoshiji I looked into strong parameters and added the following code:  `private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content_md)
 end` Now, the parameters are passed and the object is created correctly. However, the objects cannot be accessed. It returns the error: "Couldn't find Post with 'id'=123" Where it thinks that the title is the id. Why is the show method being passed the title instead of the id?

Comment: Right after you submit a form to create a new post record, you are redirected to the show page which raises the error "could not find Post with id = X", is that right ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes, The request is just:
Parameters:
{"id"=>"newpost"}
Where newpost is the title I put into the form.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is because you are using `FriendlyId`. You probably need to find the post in the "friendly_id" way: `@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])` (as seen in the docs https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart)

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes! That worked. I used railsbricks to set up a lot of the features like authentication, and I wasn't entirely sure what FriendlyID even did when it installed it. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. I will post an answer with the details that fixed your problem. Have fun with Rails :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't define the `post_params` as you should do (if using Rails 4 OR using the StrongParameters gem):

```
# posts_controller
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit([:list_of_allowed_attributes_here])
end
```

---

I see you are using FriendlyId. In order to find back the record with it's friendly ID, you have to find it like this:

```
@post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

Because `params[:id]` is not a regular integer as Rails expects but a `FriendlyId` (string containing keywords and stuff).